# Timeout on a java util scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have the following problem, I have a simple TCP class in my application that sends a message off to a device for a query, the device then responds with the message however there is no end of line character of any description because it is coming from a serial converter, after initially atempting to use the readline function and discovering it requires the eol character before outputting I have tried the scanner function which works fine unless the device doesnt reply to that request for some reason, my application then freezes, is it possible to set a timeout on the scanner function so that it then drops the connection and moves on or is there a better way to do this? my code is below:

```
public String Send_TCP ( InetAddress IPAddress, int POrt, String InData) throws IOException
         {      

        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(IPAddress, POrt);
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        ;

        System.out.print("Connected, Sending:"+ InData);

        out.println(InData);
        System.out.println("Equals");
        String str1 = new Scanner(in).useDelimiter(">").next() + ">";
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println("Equals");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        read.close();
        socket.close();
        return str1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe the following achieves what I need it to, basically checking if the buffer exists, if it doesnt then it waits and checks again avoiding the trap of the scanner function if the message never arrives if it does it reads it.

```
    try {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
    int count = 1;

        do { 
            if (rd.ready()){
                System.out.println ("Response Ready");
                str = new Scanner(rd).useDelimiter(">").next()+">";
                count = 501;
            }
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println ("Response Not Ready" + count);
            count ++;
        } while (count < 25);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly but you can set a timeout on the socket: `socket.setSoTimeout(int timeout)`.
See: [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that now but unfortunately it doesnt work, the issue is that when it hits the Scanner if the scanner is empty then the program waits, preventing the socket from closing on the idle timeout. Basically what I need is if the scanner finds the buffered reader empty then keep checking for a specified timeout before stopping and closing the connection.